# SetWindowsHookEx - difference between VK_LSHIFT and "Search" keyboard button

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I use SetWindowsHookEx to catch keyboard events

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0)
```

Here is HookCallback

```
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        // the action is valid: HC_ACTION.
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            printf("%ld\n", kbdStruct.vkCode);
        }
    }
}
```

When press "left shift" output is

```
160
```

when press "search" button (button with loupe icon on notebooks) output is

```
160
91
132
```

How to check if "left shift" or "search" button is pressed inside HookCallback ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

160 is `VK_LSHIFT`, 91 is `VK_LWIN`, and 132 is `VK_F21`. See [Virtual-Key Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes). The only standardized Search key is `VK_BROWSER_SEARCH`, so clearly your keyboard manufacturer is using a non-standard key for its Search key.

You need to remember the keys you see from one event to the next as needed, eg:

```c
bool LeftShiftIsDown = false;
bool LeftWinIsDown = false;
bool F21IsDown = false;
bool SearchIsDown = false;

LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kbdStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*) lParam;
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            printf("%ld is down\n", kbdStruct->vkCode);
            switch (kbdStruct->vkCode)
            {
                case VK_LSHIFT:
                    LeftShiftIsDown = true;
                    break;
            case VK_LWIN:
                    LeftWinIsDown = true;
                    break;
            case VK_F21:
                    F21IsDown = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (LeftShiftIsDown && LeftWinIsDown && F21IsDown)
            {
                if (!SearchIsDown)
                {
                    SearchIsDown = true;
                    printf("Search is down\n");
                }
            }
        }
        else if (wParam == WM_KEYUP)
        {
            printf("%ld is up\n", kbdStruct->vkCode);
            switch (kbdStruct->vkCode)
            {
                case VK_LSHIFT:
                    LeftShiftIsDown = false;
                    break;
                case VK_LWIN:
                    LeftWinIsDown = false;
                    break;
                case VK_F21:
                    F21IsDown = false;
                    break;
            }

            if (!(LeftShiftIsDown && LeftWinIsDown && F21IsDown))
            {
                if (SearchIsDown)
                {
                    SearchIsDown = false;
                    printf("Search is up\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: @RemyLebrau thank you. Finally I catch "VK_F21" and check if "VK_LSHIFT" and "VK_LWIN" is pressed with GetKeyState function