# SetWindowsHookEx - cancel Winkey + L (pc lock)

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Use SetWindowsHookEx to catch keyboard events

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, HookCallback, NULL, 0)
```

With this code try to prevent pc locking

```
LRESULT __stdcall HookCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
        {
            kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);
            // Winkey or l
            if (kbdStruct.vkCode == VK_LWIN || kbdStruct.vkCode == 0x4C)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(_hook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Looks like "l" button is canceled: it is not possible to use "l" in notepad for example. But pc still locking is press Winkey + l.

Comment: Like CTRL+ALT+DEL, I'm 99% certain that's an OS level hook that controls `WIN+L` for security purposes.

Comment: Any work around?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I got a bluetooth keyboard with F1-F12 buttons mapped for specific functions like volume, media player and so on. I need F1-F12 have standard functions. I create utility that switch keyboard codes. All fine except F12 - keyboard send WinKey+L. And I cannot change this.

Answer (score 0):

As @selbie said that, you will not hook controls `WIN+L` for security purposes.

But if you want to use F12 keyboard to send WinKey+L, I will recommend you to use [LockWorkStation()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-lockworkstation?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function instead.

> Locks the workstation's display. Locking a workstation protects it
>   from unauthorized use.

The least code:

```
if (nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *kbdStruct = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            printf("%ld is down\n", kbdStruct->vkCode);
            switch (kbdStruct->vkCode)
            {
            case VK_F12:
                LockWorkStation();
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

In addition, I noticed that your previous post was about the virtual key of non-standard keyboard. If you can't detect VK_F12, you can use [@Remy method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59802433/11128312).

Comment: @user1167761 hi, is the answer useful to you?